# Error code 422 while connecting from superset to Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, apache-superset, pyathena

Getting Error
**422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY** while connecting from superset to Athena (superset==1.0.1)
Using below format for connections string:

`awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}`

Comment: Resolved this by downgrading all python packages to oldest supported version.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this
`awsathena+rest://<aws_access_key_id>:<aws_secret_access_key>@athena.<region name>.amazonaws.com/<database name>?s3_staging_dir=s3://<s3 bucket>/&work_group=<work group>`